# Backend Not Found

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I load my login controller it says that the backend controller can not be found. If I change the login controller to extend the MY_Controller then it loads but if I change it back to Backend_Controller then it gives me the error.

```
-root
    -application
        -core
            -MY_Controller.php
            -Backend_Controller
        -modules
            -user
                -controllers
                    -login.php


<?php 

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends Backend_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'This is for the login form to be displayed!';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your autoloader is probably looking for `Backend_Controller` in a file with a `.php` extension.

Rename the file `Backend_Controller` to `Backend_Controller.php`.

Comment: Wow I have no idea how I missed something like that.

Comment: @user2576961 It happens to everyone; just needed another pair of eyes.